# Content in new answer posted notification banner is hardly readable

Tags: bug, user-interface, notifications, dark-mode, accessibility

### Couldn't it have been done better?

*Banner: full width*
[image: full widht]

It is very difficult to read what is written on this banner, especially those blue words.

Comment: that's... not really new, it's a banner mechanism that's been around for a while. Not quite sure why it's starting to be used now, maybe a fallback? `StackExchange.notify.show("foobar")`

Comment: yeah it has been there, but I think the color combination was different, I'm not sure

Comment: I don't think it was, we had a discussion in tavern about this banner a year or so ago, and it was orange + white/blue back then too. Guessing it just never got updated for dark mode/high contrast

Comment: @KevinB If so, you must be right.

Comment: FWIW, the link color comes from the stack you view it on. Here on meta it's maroon/red...

Comment: I usually see this underneath the question rather than above, and in gray outside with blue inside

Comment: @MrMythical yeah there it is, I have seen that one.